# Transfer array from one page to another using CURL

Tags: php, arrays, post, curl, http-post

Im trying to transfer an array of data between two files.

The **sender.php** code (the file sending the array using POST method)

```
$url = 'http://localhost/receiver.php';
$myvars = array("one","two","three")
$post_elements = array('myvars'=>$myvars);
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_elements);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );

echo "$response";
```

The **receiver.php** code (The file receiving the array from sender.php file and then take each element of the array and echo it and also put it in a document saved.txt.

```
    echo $_POST($myvars); // To test the output of the received data.

      foreach($myvars as $item) {
       if (!empty($item)) {
        echo $item."<br>";
$myfile = file_put_contents('Saved.txt', (" Name: ". ($_POST["$item"])) . PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
      }
    }
```

The array isn't being transferred to the receiver.php or I am not catching it. In the document output I have only in the place of the variable $item instead of each element of the array.

Edit:
Added the following code in the receiving file in order to get the array elements from inside but all I get is array printed out:

```
foreach( $_POST as $stuff ) {
    if( is_array( $stuff ) ) {
        foreach( $stuff as $thing ) {
            echo $thing;
        }
    } else {
        echo $stuff;
    }
}
```

By adding on the receiving file the following:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [myvars] => Array
)
```

Comment: To see what's in post in receiver, try var_dump($_POST); instead of echo $_POST($myvars); you'll be able to see if it's making it or not.

Comment: `$_POST($myvars)` does not make any sense. `$_POST` is _not_ a function! Also `$myvars` is not refined in the second script most likely. And `foreach($myvars...` has the issue, that it has nothing to do with the posted values, even _if_ `$_myvars` has been defined somewhere.

Comment: Positng a scalar array (one with numeric keys) is rarely a good idea. Either use an associative array (`array("value1"=>"one","value2"=>"two","value3"=>"three")`) or `json_serialize()` the array...

Comment: @arkascha In order to catch the data sent by $_POST($myvars) I dont need to send the variable in it? Thanks I didn't know this. Do I have to declare the $myvars variable? It doesn't get automatically declared since it gets transferred to the new page?
What are the downsides of passing it as normal arrays values?

Comment: Stop! You mix things up. `$myvars` is _not_ transferred! It is _the value of_ that variable that is transferred, not the variable as such. That is why `$myvars` is _not_ defined on the receiving side. As mentioned by @Crawdingle above: dump the contents of `$_POST` to see what _is_ transferred. And again: `$_POST(...)` does not make _any_ sense, `$_POST` is _not_ a function. You cannot use that identifier like that, it is an _array_. So you have to use square brackets: `$_POST[...]`...

Comment: Thank you this made me understand how $_POST works. 
I did a var dump and I get:
array(0) { }

Comment: @arkascha when I parse a normal array I get array(0) { }  when I pass an associative array I get the output of $_POST. Is serialization something that would solve this? As I would like to not create an associative array.

Comment: Hey, sounds great! But you are _still_ kind of "one off"... I mentioned that scalar arrays cause issues. Use an associative array for the transfer. That does _not_ mean that you have to convert the array you want to transfer into an associative one! That array should be _contained_ inside the associative array. Think of it like this: the POST request can obviously transfer multiple arguments, each one needs a name. So it transfers an array of arguments holding keys (argument name) and values (argument value). `array('myargs'=>$myargs)`

Comment: @arkascha 
I edited my code would this be correct? I am getting now array(1) { ["myvars"]=> string(5) "Array" } Also I added a code in order to retrieve the array data from the POST but I get only: array

Comment: You cannot echo an array. Have a try using `print_r(...)`  or `echo print_r(..., true)`.

Comment: @arkascha thank you for replying. I tried it but still I dont get the following: Array
(
    [myvars] => Array
)

Comment: Please dump the whole `$_POST` superglobal variable and post it here (add it to the question).

Comment: @arkascha I have just added the $_POST code, along with its output.

Comment: I do have to apologize. Just checked myself and have to admit that I got the same result. I am confused, since I did not expect that. json-encoding your payload will solve the issue for you: `array('myvars'=>json_encode($myvars))`, and I will have to think about this :-(

Comment: Of course no apology is needed my friend. Thank you @arkascha for the long and valuable help you have provided, today I learned a lot. Will I need to use json_decode($myvars) in order to use the elements in that array?
I can not up vote your comments or choose you as best answer :(
Please, submit something or copy paste the questions code with the json encode so I can choose it as best answer.

Comment: Yes, you will obviously have to decode the encoded array on the receiving side. It appears that the curl library only encodes the post fields to the first level, not in a recursive manner. No idea why that is...

Comment: An alternative would be to take care to pack the post fields in a recursive manner on the sending side. You can simply use `http_build_query()` for that. That way you can post arbitrary multidimensional array as post fields without the need to decode things on the receiving side.

Comment: I added an answer to sum up the result. That version works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the bottom line of the discussion in the comments above leads to this result:

The sending part:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/out.php';
$myvars = array("one","two","three");
$post_elements = array('myvars'=>$myvars);
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_elements));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
print_r($response);
```

The receiving part:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```

The output on the sending side is:

```
Array ( [myvars] => Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => three ) )
```

which basically says that you can simply use `$_POST['myvars']` on the receiving side which will exactly hold the scalar array you want to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

try to  serialize the array because it always helps me :

```
$url = 'http://localhost/receiver.php';
$myvars = array("one","two","three");
$myvars_post=join(" ",$myvars);
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "array=".urldecode($myvars_post));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );

echo "$response";
```

and in the receiver.php use :

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing. Sadly I ran your code but I get array(0) { } 
Also I am not the one who -1 as I cant even vote up yet, just joined.

Comment: it's ok actually it was my fault please check what i have added to the code

Comment: I ran it but I get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
on: $myvars_post = join(" ",$myvars);